# Entity Framework Call Oracle Stored Procedure with Output Parameters using Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I want to call a simple stored procedure that has 2 output parameters, an int and a string. I want to use my generic repository pattern to get the data.

**Here is the Oracle stored procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure dummy_proc (
    dummy1 in number,
    dummy2 in varchar2,
    dummy3 out number,
    dummy4 out varchar2)
is
begin
    dummy3 := 2500 + dummy1;
    dummy4 := 'Sample text! -> ' || dummy2;
end dummy_proc;
```

**My generic repository method:**

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<T> SQLQuery<T>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
  return Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters);
}
```

**I created a simple class to hold the 2 output parameter values in:**

```
public class Test 
{
  public int dummy1 { get; set; }
  public string dummy2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my manager class I'll use to call the repository method:**

```
var dummy1 = new OracleParameter("dummy1", OracleDbType.Int32,50, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = id };
dummy1.Size = 50;

var dummy2 = new OracleParameter("dummy2", OracleDbType.Varchar2,200, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = model };
dummy2.Size = 200;

var dummy3 = new OracleParameter("dummy3", OracleDbType.Int32,50, ParameterDirection.Output) ;
dummy3.Size = 50;

var dummy4 = new OracleParameter("dummy4", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200, ParameterDirection.Output) ;
dummy4.Size = 200;

object[] parameters = new object[] { dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4 };

var test = _repository.SQLQuery<Test>("BEGIN dummy_proc(:dummy1, :dummy2, :dummy3, :dummy4); END;", parameters);

var param3 = dummy3.Value;
var param4 = dummy4.Value;
```

This code seems to call the stored procedure correctly but my output parameters are always null. I've searched through several articles but none are using the same patterns that I've found.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of SqlQuery. because there's many problem when using SqlQuery with Oracle stored procedure.

**Update 1**
I found output result that returned from Oracle was stored in same variable that created for `OracleParamter`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the repository method and using the ExecuteSqlCommand instead of SqlQuery, this is now returning the correct output. In my case, my output parameters are just returning string information so I just concatenate the results and return a JsonResultMessage.

```
 public JsonResultMessage ExecuteOracleStoredProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var result = new JsonResultMessage
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Successfully executed procedure."
        };
        try
        {
            var results = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);
            var output = new OracleParameter("p_message", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output) { Size = 999000 };
            foreach (OracleParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                if (parameter.Direction.Equals(ParameterDirection.Output))
                {
                    result.Message = parameter.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = false;
            result.Message = "Error executing procedure: ." + ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The JsonResultMessage is a simple container for my results:

```
 public class JsonResultMessage
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I call this method I use the following syntax:

```
resultMessage = _repository.ExecuteOracleStoredProcedure("begin IMACMPS1.com_check_end_item(:param1, :param2, :param3);end;",
        new OracleParameter("p_to_site", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = siteCode, Size = 50 },
        new OracleParameter("p_part_no ", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = partNo, Size = 35 }
      );
```

Where check_end_item is the name of my procedure.